# How to set argument for main class while installation

Tags: install4j

I need to set the main class for a launcher during the installation. So is there any argument that can be set in the .vmoption file to change the main class provided in the launcher. I need to change the main class if I am installing the installer in some other mode.

Answer (score 0):

The main class of a launcher in install4j cannot be changed as of install4j 6. The workaround is easy, though. Just create a wrapper class that calls the desired main class based on an argument or a VM parameter.